# create constructor of a database for a different thread

Tags: android, multithreading, constructor

For manipulating a database I've created a class DBAdapter() that extends SQLiteHelper...this class has this constructor:

```
public DBAdapter(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    this.myContext = context;

}
```

Now that  works fine in any activity of the package:

`DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);`

What I'm trying to do is to create a new thread and to acces the database from that thread.

The problem is that WHEN i TRY TO  DO

`db=new DBAdapter(this);`   inside that class it tells me "wrong context"!!!

Should I create a new constructor in the DBAdapter() class for my new class???Are there allowed two constructers in the DBAdapter()??

This is how my class looks like:

```
public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable{


public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket){
    this.clientSocket=clientSocket;
}



public void run(){
    try{        
         Scanner is =new Scanner(new DataInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

         while (is.hasNext()) {
             longitude = is.next();

             Log.d("Longitudine:",longitude); 
             latitude=is.next();
             Log.d("Latitudine:",latitude); 

         }

        is.close();
        clientSocket.close();
            }
    catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
       }
}
```

How should my constructer look like? Should be called in the run() method of this class?Thx!

---

```
public class Server1 extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.server1);
    DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);

    MultiThreadedServer server = new MultiThreadedServer(6000);

    new Thread(server).start();
}

}
```

How could I pass the Server1 activity to the thread????

Here is MultiThreadedServer which cllas for WorkerRunnable:

public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable {

```
protected int serverPort=6000;

public static String SERVERIP="10.0.2.15";

protected ServerSocket serverSocket=null;

protected boolean isStopped=false;

protected Thread runningThread=null;

 public static int clientconnection = 0;

public MultiThreadedServer(int port){

    this.serverPort=port;
}


 public void run(){

        synchronized(this){

            this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();

        }

openServerSocket();


while(!isStopped()){

    Socket clientSocket=null;

    try{
        System.out.println("Serverul asteapta clienti spre conectare");

        clientSocket=this.serverSocket.accept();

        clientconnection++;

        System.out.println("Serverul a acceptat clientul cu numarul:"+clientconnection) ;
        //Log.d("Server:","s-a acceptat un nou client");




        }
    catch(IOException e){

        if(isStopped()) {

            System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
            return;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(

            "Error accepting client connection", e);

    }
      new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket)).start();
}
  System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
}

 private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }

    private void openServerSocket() {
        try {
            InetSocketAddress serverAddr =new InetSocketAddress(SERVERIP,serverPort);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.bind(serverAddr);
            Log.d("Server:","bind-ul a fost realizat!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 6000", e);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Your provided Runnable does not call a DBAdapter constructor, so it makes it hard to figure out where you context is coming from. It seems like you are doing new DBAdapter(this) in a Thread, but since a Thread is not a context, that can't be true.

Comment: i guess I didn't make it very clear!!!In my Runnable class I should call the constructor which should be defined in the DBAdapter() class.The code provided is for the class which should call the constructer(which I don't know how it looks like,yet!)

Comment: DBAdapter(this)... I said that I do this in a context...a class that extends an Activity...and I can't figure out how to do it in a thread.....the Runnable provided is in the thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);` within your main Activity then pass it to your Thread through its constructor.
Or you could pass the main Activity to the Thread (via the constructor) then create the DBAdapter with `DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(<activityVar>);`

Edit:
So, your `MultiThreadedServer`'s constructor will look like this `public MultiThreadedServer(int port, DBAdatpter db){` and you will pass in the `db` from `Server1`.  Throw it into a global var within `MultiThreadedServer` and pass it to `WorkerRunnable` via the updated constructor `public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, DBAdapter db){`.

Comment: Is `MultiThreadedServer` the same thing as `WorkerRunnable`?  you don't seem to instantiate a `WorkerRunnable` anywhere.

Comment: I've put my MUltiThreadedServer code which calls for WorkerRunnable.Thank u!!

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.....I have no error,I hope it works further.Thank u a looootttt!!!!